# The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using Microsoft Access 2007 to move and massage some data between two SQL Servers.  Yesterday everything was working correctly, I was able to run queries, update data, and delete data.

Today I opened up the Access database to finish my data migration and am now receiving the following message when I try to run some update queries:

> The action or event has been blocked
>   by Disabled Mode.

Any ideas what this is talking about?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try and see if this works:

1. Click on 'External Data' tab
2. There should be a Security Warning that states "Certain content in the database has been disabled"
3. Click the 'Options' button
4. Select 'Enable this content' and click the OK button

Comment: If the Security Warning isn't displayed, then try to create a new pass trhough query to the external database, then the Security Warning will show up.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this with Access options.

Go to the Office Button --> Access Options --> Trust Center --> Trust Center Settings Button --> Message Bar

In the right hand pane I selected the radio button "Show the message bar in all applications when content has been blocked."

Closed Access, reopened the database and got the warning for blocked content again.

Comment: This is best option for Access 2013 since other options on the tool ribbons--as describe by others--do not exist .  Besides "Message Bar" tab, it might be necessary to check "Macro Settings" tab.  In my case it was set to "Disable all macros WITHOUT notification", so I had to change it to "Disable all macros WITH notification" for Access to show the message bar allowing me to enable macros (and VB code).

Answer (score 8):

No. Go to database tools (for 2007) and click checkmark on the Message Bar. Then, after the message bar apears, click on Options, and then Enable. Hope this helps.

Dimitri

Answer (score 2):

From access help:

**Stop Disabled Mode from blocking a query**
If you try to run an append query and it seems like nothing happens, check the Access status bar for the following message:

This action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode.

To stop Disabled Mode from blocking the query, you must enable the database content. You use the Options button in the Message Bar to enable the query.

Enable the append query
In the Message Bar, click Options.
In the Microsoft Office Security Options dialog box, click Enable this content, and then click OK.
If you don't see the Message Bar, it may be hidden. You can show it, unless it has also been disabled. If the Message Bar has been disabled, you can enable it.

Show the Message Bar
If the Message Bar is already visible, you can skip this step.

On the Database Tools tab, in the Show/Hide group, select the Message Bar check box. 
If the Message Bar check box is disabled, you will have to enable it.

Enable the Message Bar
If the Message Bar check box is enabled, you can skip this step.

Click the Microsoft Office Button , and then click Access Options.
In the left pane of the Access Options dialog box, click Trust Center.
In the right pane, under Microsoft Office Access Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings.
In the left pane of the Trust Center dialog box, click Message Bar.
In the right pane, click Show the Message Bar in all applications when content has been blocked, and then click OK.
Close and reopen the database to apply the changed setting.
 Note   When you enable the append query, you also enable all other database content.

For more information about Access security, see the article Help secure an Access 2007 database.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider self-certifying your projects:

[Self-certification, digital certificate, digital signatures](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-trust-by-adding-a-digital-signature-5f4ebff3-360d-4b61-b2f8-ce0dfb53adf6)

Answer (score 1):

On the ribbon,Go to Database Tools
under "Show/Hide", make sure the Message bar is checked (turned on)
Then click on the gray message bar, click database options.
From there you can modify your security options.  Just enable these types of content.

You should be good to go after this.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue is that your database may be in a "non-trusted" location. Go to the trust center settings and add your database location to the trusted locations list.