# How to override MS Access Disabled Mode programmatically

Tags: .net, ms-access

I have an application I'm supporting that manages instances of MS Access 2010. I've noticed that when it opens Access databases that have been downloaded, they open in Disabled Mode. This prevents the user from doing things like executing update queries, displaying the message:

> The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101779/the-action-or-event-has-been-blocked-by-disabled-mode) solution for turning it off through the UI, but I need to be able to accomplish this programmatically. Is there any way to turn off Disabled Mode using .NET instead of relying on user interaction?

Also worth noting, the domain where the files are coming from is included in ZoneMap/Domains registry entries, so the source should be considered a trusted location.

Comment: Are you saving the files to a trusted location?

Comment: This turned out to be the solution I was able to come up with. I have my application modify the registry to add the location of the files being accessed to the trusted locations list. This way, it requires no user interaction to prevent Disabled Mode from kicking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have the reference handy, but if memory serves that is supposed to be a security feature. There is, by design, no way to programmatically turn off that mode.

What you can do is have it open a window by default that tells the user how to turn the mode off.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but that's kind of what I expected to hear. Thanks.