# Access 2013 Update Query blocked by Disabled Mode

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am attempting to run an update query and receiving an error in the status bar "The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode".

EVERYONE IS RECOMMENDING THIS ARTICLE. [The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101779/the-action-or-event-has-been-blocked-by-disabled-mode)
PLEASE READ THE BULLET POINTS BELOW.  That article does NOT fix the issue

1) I have no messages asking to enable or anything like that. 
2) I have checked and there is nothing labeled security warnings or anything like that on the External Data tab
3) I have checked the Access Option for Trust Center Settings "Show Message Bar" is checked. 
4) I have googled anything else I can find. There was a reference to Database Tools tab, but there should be some "Show/Hide" section that doesn't exist and

I can't seem to find what they're asking about.  Any help would be so appreciated.

Though I was working with the tech guys at my work and they were saying that it's not a trusted location. 
I answered my own question.  I'm on a work computer, it's managed (naturally).  So there is an un-editable list under Trusted Locations.  When I moved my DB to one of those locations, all started working fine.

Hope this helps other people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101779/the-action-or-event-has-been-blocked-by-disabled-mode)

Comment: I referenced the linked article in my original post. I'm using 2013 and the original article doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: I don't see it referenced anywhere. That post has several answers. Have you tried them all? (Including moving your database to a trusted location)